# CSS position between Win / Linux / Mac Logo Position

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, firefox

i've a little bit trouble to fix one thing, may you could help me out with it?

I try to make Chrome/Firefox works with a Logo sliding problem. You can see here the first pci is how does it looks like in win with chrome or firefox. IE looks normal like the second pic.

What did i wrong in the code? many thanks in advance.

http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2013-067oqb8.png

http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2013-06u6rho.png

Comment: Maybe you could provide relevant html/css? (link to test site or jsfiddle)

Comment: Please don't use the fix tag unless you are talking about FIX protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you unless I see the CSS.  Post the css on something like pastbin.com or if it isn't real long then add it to your question and then you are likely to get some answers, but I can't tell you what is wrong with your CSS from a picture of the results.  Too many possibilities.

Now I'm wishing I had asked for a demonstration instead.  Am I correct in thinking that the text is part of a horizontal menu and the logo is completely separate and not contained by the text container at all?  If this is the case and the image looks and behaves like you want then perhaps it is the menu that needs tweaking to get it to match up correctly.  At first I was thinking this was something like a div containing text and an image or having an image as a background.

If you could go ahead and post a link to a page or a pastebin or something that has the html and the css for the menu and the logo together then I'll try it out myself and see if I can find the solution.  Someone else may already see it, but I'm still not seeing the clear picture of your situation or a resolution to your problem yet.

Comment: #slidingLogo {
 height: 58px;
 width: 80px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 background: url("../core_images/logo_klein_2.png")
}

Comment: behind the sliding logo is a js as well.
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".contentpane p").animate({
     opacity: 1
    }, 2500);

    $("#slidingLogo").hide().fadeIn(70).animate({
     top : 25,
     opacity : 0.3,
     left : 135
    }, 700).animate({
     left : 120,
     opacity : 0.8
    }, 500).animate({
     left : 125,
     opacity : 1
    }, 400).animate({
     left : 115,
     opacity : 1
    }, 300).animate({
     left : 110,
     opacity : 1
    }, 200);
   });
  </script>